# How do search engines generate related searches?

Tags: machine-learning, ranking, natural-language

I would like to know how search engines like Bing generate related searches when the user starts typing into the search box.

From what I gather, there has to be some sort of a ranking algorithm where the words which the user enters first get bagged, and then the closest related search pops up, from a history of past related searches. The ranking is probably influenced by user's previous search history.

I heard that Bing's search engine is powered by RankNet algorithm, but I can't find a good tutorial on how this process works. I would like to find an article or a paper which I can implement myself in Python or Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Python already has a free module that can handle topic modelling in text. You may want just want to use that because text processing can be dirty business (a lot of junk), so I would use their modules located [here](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) and you can read about the algorithms separately.

A good introduction to statistical nlp is ofcourse Christopher Manning `Foundations of Statistical NLP` book. A very popular indexing algorithm is the Latent Semantic Indexing algorithm found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing).